# What is a control area?

Tags: faa-regulations, commercial-aviation, general-aviation, easa-regulations

I read a controlled area is a controlled airspace extending upwards from a specified limit above the earth.

But what is the difference between a contolled airspace  and a control area.Also what about lateral limits. Also who decides the level limit...

Comment: What books are you reading?  Where will you be flying?  Your study material for the area where you plan to fly should explain all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first question can be answered directly from the definitions:

> [CONTROL AREA [ICAO]](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/pcg_html/glossary-c.html#%24CONTROL%20AREA%20%5BICAO%5D)- A controlled airspace extending upwards from a specified limit above the earth.
>
> [CONTROLLED AIRSPACE [ICAO]](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/pcg_html/glossary-c.html#%24CONTROLLED%20AIRSPACE%20%5BICAO%5D)- An airspace of defined dimensions within which air traffic control service is provided to IFR flights and to VFR flights in accordance with the airspace classification.
> Note: Controlled airspace is a generic term which covers ATS airspace Classes A, B, C, D, and E.

The difference between *controlled airspace* and *a control area* is the difference between *asphalt* and *a highway.* Controlled airspace is the material from which a control area is constructed.

As to your second question, the local [civil aviation authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_aviation_authority) and/or the [air navigation service provider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_navigation_service_provider) will determine the locally preferred configuration of a control area to provide the most beneficial service to airspace users within the limits of available resources.

Comment: please do not answer a question than not only is probably in need of closing, but that even you voted to close.